# Prevention of Cmd+Shift+Q alert emergence in sandboxed application

Tags: cocoa, sandbox, hotkeys

I block the screen with my own window in my app. and I need to prevent the emergence of this alert which called by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> system hotkey.

[image]

Comment: Why are you sandboxing your application? I rather doubt you could put it into the App Store.

Comment: my app is something like this https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keycard/id578513438?mt%3D12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [kiosk mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/KioskMode/). There are several things you may want to block, including “session termination” (the logout commands, among other things), application switching and Exposé, and the Apple menu; that document describes how you can block whichever items you want to block.

Comment: NSApplicationPresentationDisableAppleMenu - that's I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @myke: Don't assume that DisableAppleMenu will completely prevent logout. There are other ways to log out of the system that don't involve the Apple menu.

Comment: can you tell me about other ways to turn of my full screen app with these options?
    NSApplicationPresentationOptions options =
        NSApplicationPresentationHideDock |
        NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar |
        NSApplicationPresentationDisableAppleMenu |
        NSApplicationPresentationDisableForceQuit |
        NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching |
        NSApplicationPresentationDisableSessionTermination |
        NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication;

Comment: @myke: I don't understand what you mean by “turn of my full screen app”.

Comment: when I block screen with my full screen window I use these presentation options for NSApp, there are only NSTextField for password input on the screen. the correct password must be the only one way to unlock my Mac (except "Power" button ;))